# Joomla. How to make button "Click to see more" on bottom of page

Tags: button, joomla, scroll, click

In Joomla page I have big content and I want to make not pages like 1,2,3...etc., but like in Facebook scroll down till you see button "Click to see more" and without refresh It add some data to bottom of page.
I don't know how to make It, maybe here are any extensions? Or any scripts? So hard to make It? 
Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1):

To do it the ajax way, i.e. only loading content when you intend to show it, you will need to write a custom jQuery function that onload:

1. finds the "next page" button and store the url into a variable (this will contain the whole url followed by &pagenumber=2 or /page/2 or something similar).
2. remove its handler and replace it with a custom ajax call:
3. jQuery.get with the url you just stored adding &format=raw (this will return the content of the next page, without the rest of the template, and without any scripts and css - which you have already loaded)
4. on success remove the "next page" button you modified,
5. then insert in its place the html received from the ajax call,
6. repeat from n.1 until there is no "next page" button

Answer (score 0):

After reading your query i come to know that you have a large content in your joomla article. Once the page loads you want to show some part of content n later part shows once clicked on see more button. If i'm correct then write script inside your article add div tags into your content. Apply display none property to the content of div which you want to show on click. Using JQuery or Js you can show the hidden part once clicked on button.

Comment: I have many videos uploaded in my site. When I click "View all videos" I want to make button something like "See more" which shows 20~ more videos on the page or auto update page with videos when I reach bottom of page. Thank you, I will try analyze JQuery